# Ajax URL issue when sending data to Controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to send data to the controller using Ajax. But I keep getting an error in the console when the page loads saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` and is directed to the URL param line in the Ajax call.
This is what I have.

```
// Script
$.ajax({
  type: "GET"
  url: "games/show_games_week"
  data:{ week_number: week }
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Then my route is set up like so.

```
# Route
get "games/show_games_week"
```

Then my controller action is this

```
# Controller
def show_games_week
  foo = params[:week_number]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => foo }
  end
end
```

This must be the way my URL is set up...right? I've done research and the URL is set up like most other answers I've seen on S.O. being `url: "controller_name/controller_action"`

Any Idea what else this can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing commas:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "games/show_games_week",
    data:{ week_number: week },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The `$.ajax()` method expects a valid object literal as input, or `string, object`.

Comment: Thank you for catching that... I was in such tunnel vision.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)